# is this proof correct-L is a linear transformation show that L(0)=0

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

take $a>0$

if $L$ is a linear transformation-

$a\cdot f(0)=f(a\cdot 0)$ is true
$\implies a\cdot f(0)=f(0) \implies f(0)=0$;  $[a>0]$.....(step 3)

alternatively

we know $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

$\implies f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$

$\implies f(0)=2\cdot f(0)$

$\implies f(0)=0$.....(step 3)

I don't want to know other ways of proving this. just interested in knowing whether this particular proof is valid esp validity of step 3 and if so what is missing from the proof( none of the vector space axioms seem to be relevant here for proof)

Comment: You give two proofs, not one proof. In the first proof, what happens if $a=1$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thanks for formatting it! newbie here...and the prompt answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second proof is correct, assuming that the field is not of characteristic $2$. The first one is only correct is you specify that $a\neq 1$ (if $a=1$, then $f(0) = af(0)$ doesn't tell us anything). In fact, it would be better to show your work on that: if $a \neq 1$,

$$af(0) = f(0) \implies af(0) - f(0) = 0 \implies (a-1)f(0) = 0 \implies f(0) = 0$$
since $a-1\neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

You have to be precise in what you're saying. Your question is: If $L$ is a transformation linear between $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces, then $L(0)=0$. Thus replace "$a>0$" by a different element of identity in $\mathbb{K}$ and say that the vectors belong to the domain of $L$.
In the more you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This proof works if the scalar field has characteristic different from 2.  A proof that works for all fields is as follows (${\bf 0}$ denotes the zero vector, $0$ the zero scalar):
$$
L({\bf 0}) = L(0 {\bf 0}) = 0 L({\bf 0}) = 0.
$$